# Custom excel concatenation

Tags: excel, vba

Custom Concatenation in excel. I need to be able to choose my own delimiter, and select a range of cells to concatenate. Is there a code block capable of doing this?

Comment: In the latest OFFICE 365 there is a formula TEXTJOIN().

Comment: If your data is in cells A1 and B1, then how about in C1 `=A1&"mycustomdelimiter"&B1` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you were thinking. You can set the range (horizontal or vertical) and a custom delimiter of any length. If you want to get fancy you can add a pre-delimiter to the beginning of each string as well.

```
Function CONCATRANGE(conc As Range, delim As String, Optional preDelim As String, Optional trailing As Boolean)
Dim c
Dim concformula As String
For Each c In conc
    If Not c.Value = "" Then
        concformula = concformula & preDelim & c.Value & delim
    End If
Next
If delim <> "" And trailing = 0 Then
    concformula = Left(concformula, Len(concformula) - Len(delim))
End If
CONCATRANGE = concformula
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

you can exploit the `Join()` function like follows:

for "1D" ranges

```
Function CUSTOMCONCAT1D(rng As Range, delim As String)

If rng.Rows.Count > 1 Then
    CUSTOMCONCAT1D = Join(Application.Transpose(rng), delim)
Else
    CUSTOMCONCAT1D = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rng)), delim)
End If

End Function
```

for "2D" ranges

```
Function CUSTOMCONCAT2D(rng As Range, delim As String)
Dim i As Long
If rng.Rows.Count > 1 And rng.Columns.Count > 1 Then
    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        CUSTOMCONCAT2D = CUSTOMCONCAT2D & Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rng.Rows(i))), delim) & delim
    Next i
Else
    CUSTOMCONCAT2D = CUSTOMCONCAT1D(rng, delim)
End If

End Function
```